# How to get the hours difference between two date objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, object

I got two Date objects and I want to calculate the difference in hours.

If the difference in hours is less than 18 hours, I want to push the date object into an array.

Javascript / jQuery, doesn't really matter; what works the best will do.

Comment: This question is about the difference in hours between dates, so it shouldn't have been closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 314, accepted):

The simplest way would be to directly subtract the date objects from one another.

For example:

```
var hours = Math.abs(date1 - date2) / 36e5;
```

The subtraction returns the difference between the two dates in milliseconds. `36e5` is the scientific notation for `60*60*1000`, dividing by which converts the milliseconds difference into hours.

Comment: The engineer in me would prefer to see `3.6e6` ([normalized scientific notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation)) instead of `36e5`. The book reader, however, would prefer `360000`.

Comment: To each his own.

Comment: @Blazemonger 360 000? I would prefer 3 600 000 ;)

Comment: Good approach, although I get 2.0001191666666664 due to large number handling inaccuracies. 
I suggest supplying the result to Math.floor like `var hours = Math.floor(Math.abs(date1 - date2) / 36e5);`

Comment: To make code more readable to the average developer, I would stick with 60*60*1000 (or use 3600000 with a comment). 36e5 or 3.6e6 assumes that the developer knows scientific notation, which is not always the case.

Comment: This seems to only take hours and not the difference in days in that calculation.

Comment: @Jayson I’m not sure I understand. The question is indeed about the difference in hours. If you need the difference in days, divide the result by 24.

Comment: @Boaz - correct. Maybe I misunderstood the question. But let's say I have a date object of 9/27/2019 00:00:00 and another date object of 9/29/2019 01:00:00 I seem to get the answer of 1hr, when it should in fact be 49hrs. I was able to find a fix though with the .getTime() function:                                                                  'function diff_hours(dt2, dt1)
'     {
'
'      var diff =(dt2.getTime() - dt1.getTime()) / 1000;
'      diff /= (60 * 60);
'      return Math.abs(Math.round(diff));
'
'     }

Comment: @Jayson `Math.abs(new Date('09/27/2019 00:00:00')-new Date('09/29/2019 01:00:00'))/36e5` returns `49` as expected. Is this the calculation you're making?

Comment: @Boaz - I think the issue I was having was because I was using input from a date and time picker which was a string return and not a date object. I imagine I could have converted them to a date object but using .getTime() seemed to work just as well. Plus I can use the string in other locations as vars.

Comment: with this method, 2 date with 1 day difference give me `440982` hours

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa The arithmetic operation casts the dates to their UNIX timestamp values (e.g. `.getTime()` or `.valueOf()`), before subtraction takes place. It could be the dates are really that far apart, or the specific calculation is not actually returning hours. Please share the timestamps in question.

Comment: `2020-04-22T06:00:00Z` and `2020-04-23T06:00:00Z`

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa `Math.abs((new Date('2020-04-22T06:00:00Z')-new Date('2020-04-23T06:00:00Z')))/36e5` seems to return `24`, as expected. [See demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/0Lez1duo/).

Comment: @Blazemonger Any chance you could change your number to have 5 "0"s? I copied your value and got bugs because it should be `3600000` (3.6 million), not `360000` (0.36 million).

Comment: @Blazemonger Personally I'd prefer `60*60*1000` so the origin of the resulting number is clear

Answer (score 62):

Try using `getTime` ([mdn doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime)):

```
var diff = Math.abs(date1.getTime() - date2.getTime()) / 3600000;
if (diff < 18) { /* do something */ }
```

Using `Math.abs()` we don't know which date is the smallest. This code is probably more relevant:

```
var diff = (date1 - date2) / 3600000;
if (diff < 18) { array.push(date1); }
```

Answer (score 12):

Use the timestamp you get by calling `valueOf` on the date object:

```
var diff = date2.valueOf() - date1.valueOf();
var diffInHours = diff/1000/60/60; // Convert milliseconds to hours
```