# Jquery countdown for day

Tags: jquery

I have a countdown jquery working for hour, minutes and second. So far, this worked perfectly. However I want it also count on day

This is the [JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/rrjHF/)

HTML

```
<div id="counttime">24:00:00</div>
<div id="cons"></div>
```

JQUERY

```
    function pad(num) {
  return num<10?"0"+num:num;
}
$(function() {
  var tCont = $('#counttime');
  var timer = tCont.html().split(':');

  if (timer.length === 2) timer.unshift(0);
  var endMilli= timer[0]*60*60*1000;
  endMilli += timer[1]*60*1000
  endMilli += timer[2]*1000;
  if(endMilli > 0) {
    var endTime = new Date(Date.now()+endMilli);   
$("#cons").append("<br>"+endTime);
    var tId = setInterval(function() {
      var diff = endTime.getTime()-Date.now();
      if (diff<=0) {
        tCont.html("00:00:00");
        clearInterval(tId);
      }
      else {
        var d = new Date(diff);
        hh = pad(d.getUTCHours()); 
        mm = pad(d.getMinutes());
        ss = pad(d.getSeconds());
        tCont.html(""+hh+":"+mm+":"+ss);
      }
    },300);      
  }
});
```

Comment: sorry... what do you mean by day?

Comment: your question is not entirely clear. Instead of saying "it's working fine", can you please make an effort to describe what's the behaviour of "it's working fine"

Comment: @ArunPJohny mean i want countdown with day,hour,min,second... now only hour,min,second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to adjust your code to allow for 4 parts and then add a line to evaluate the days:

```
dd = pad( (diff - diff % (864e5))/864e5 ),
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/rrjHF/88/)

Answer (score 0):

Your `hh` part should multiply by days!

```
hh = pad(d.getUTCHours() + d.getDay()*24);
```

You should add months as well... not sure if this is easy.
Or you can try this:

```
var hours = Math.abs(date1 - date2) / 36e5;
hh = pad(hours);
```

Where `36e5 = 60*60*1000` milliseconds

Comment: I got from this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19225414/how-to-get-the-hours-difference-between-two-date-objects

Comment: can u make it in js fiddle ?