# Javascript, check if timestamp is more than 6 hours from now

Tags: javascript

I am trying to check if a timestamp I have in local storage is more than 6 hours old, I don't believe my logic is correct. Here is what I have so far.

```
function checkBasket() {
  const basket = localStorage.getItem('user_basket');

  if (basket) {
    var sixHours = 5 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

    return ((new Date) - JSON.parse(basket).timestamp) < sixHours;
  }

  return false;
}
```

So I am trying to get this function to return true if the localstorage basket.timestamp is less than 6 hours old, otherwise false.

Comment: `var sixHours = 5 * 60 * 60 * 1000;` - that's 5 hours, sparky

Answer (score 3):

```js
var date1 = new Date("Mon Oct 24 2016 04:22:12 GMT+0530 (IST)");
var date2 = new Date("Mon Oct 24 2016 10:22:12 GMT+0530 (IST)");
var hours = Math.floor(Math.abs(date1 - date2) / 36e5);
console.log(hours);
```

You Can Make Use Of This Code Snippet

Reference:
[How to get the hours difference between two date objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19225414/how-to-get-the-hours-difference-between-two-date-objects)

Answer (score 2):

```
var diffHours = Math.abs(date1 - date2) / 36e5
```

The subtraction returns the difference between the two dates in *milliseconds*. **36e5** is the scientific notation for 60*60*1000, dividing by which converts the *milliseconds* difference into *hours*

Comment: OK, so what's wrong with the OP's code? (Other than that they're using 5 hours rather than 6?)