# How to subtract hours within object in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to calculate work hours between two Date. I set up two date.

```
    var startDate = new Date("2/25/2017 20:30");
    var endDate = new Date ("3/28/2017 20:58");
```

I set up days like objects in which i have work start and work end.

```
var monday = {"start":"09:00", "end":"17:00"};
var tuesday = {"start":"09:00", "end":"17:00"};
var wednesday = {"start":"09:00", "end":"17:00"};
var thursday = {"start":"09:00", "end":"17:00"};
var friday = {"start":"08:00", "end":"13:00"};
var saturday = {"start":"08:00", "end":"11:00"};
var sunday = {"start":"08:00", "end":"09:00"};
```

Then i put all objects in array:

```
 var workDays = [monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday, sunday];
```

I don't know how to subtract hours in each day. For example, in monday: 17:00 - 09:00 = 8 hours.

I tried this:

```
var mondayStart = monday.start;
var mondayEnd= monday.end;
```

In console i get right start and end time of monday object, but i have problem with subtraction.

```
var mondayDifference = mondayEnd - mondayStart;

console.log(mondayDifference);
```

But, in console i get: NaN (not a number).

I'll be thankfull for any hints or help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the hours difference between two date objects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19225414/how-to-get-the-hours-difference-between-two-date-objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are given the real case not only POC, `parseInt` will be enough to get the difference

```
var mondayDifference = parseInt(monday.end) - parseInt(monday.start);
                       // "17:00" will be 17     ..so on
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It makes sense now.

Comment: You are Welcome 