# JS Date API: Diff between two dates in hours – Odd behaviour with current Date

Tags: javascript, date, datediff

I know this is a basic question that may have been answered before, but I've been scratching my head about this one. So here it is:

I want to get the number of hours between a set date and the current time.

I have attempted the following (this was done on 2018/05/23 21:35 UTC-4:00):

```
(new Date(2018, 05, 24).getTime() - new Date(2018,05,23).getTime())/(3600*1000) // 24

(new Date(2018, 05, 24).getTime() - new Date().getTime())/(3600*1000) // 746.4949...
```

Oddly, subtracting tomorrow from current time gives 746 hours. The expectation is that I would have gotten ~2.4h. I also attempted the following variations:

```
// Straight up dates

(new Date(2018, 05, 24) - new Date(2018,05,23))/(3600*1000) // 24

(new Date(2018, 05, 24) - new Date())/(3600*1000) // 746.4949...

// Using valueOf

(new Date(2018, 05, 24).valueOf() - new Date(2018,05,23).valueOf())/(3600*1000) // 24

(new Date(2018, 05, 24).valueOf() - new Date().valueOf())/(3600*1000) // 746.4949...

// Using Date.now()

(new Date(2018, 05, 24).valueOf() - new Date().now())/(3600*1000) // 746.4949...
```

Any idea why this is a problem, and how to solve it?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Month numbers in Javascript dates are zero-based, so `new Date(2018, 05, 24)` is June 24, 2018, not May 24, 2018. Subtract 1 from the month number to get the result you expect.

```js
console.log((new Date(2018, 4, 24).getTime() - new Date().getTime())/(3600*1000))
```

This prints about `2.14` when I run it at May 23 21:50 UTC-04:00.

Comment: Wonderful, thanks for your answer! I completely forgot about that. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Parameters)

> **Note:** The argument month is 0-based. This means that January = 0 and December = 11.

The simplest way to get the difference between two dates on hours, ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19225540/923426))

```
var hours = Math.abs(date1 - date2) / 36e5;
```

The subtraction returns the difference between the two dates in milliseconds. 36e5 is the scientific notation for 60*60*1000, dividing by which converts the milliseconds' difference into hours.